# Template class vector erase not working

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, erase

I'm working on a project that includes a handmade Set of sorts using a template class with two types and vectors (which I may change to pointers but not at the moment).

Adding and outputting values works fine, and I'm able to access the key and values using eachother as well.

However I'm having problems with removing values. This is the code I have for it:

```
bool Remove(Tkey key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        if (keyPtr[i] == key)
        {
            keyPtr.erase(keyPtr.begin() + (i-1));
            valuePtr.erase(valuePtr.begin() + (i-1));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So that when I want to use it it will look like this:

```
cout << "Remove Value 6" << endl;
list.Remove(6);
```

What I expect from vectors is when that calls, the data with the key as 6 would be removed. However I get this as my output:

Key     : 0     Value   : 0

Key     : 1     Value   : 3

Key     : 2     Value   : 6

Key     : 3     Value   : 9

Key     : 4     Value   : 12

Key     : 5     Value   : 15

Key     : 6     Value   : 18

Key     : 7     Value   : 21

Key     : 8     Value   : 24

Key     : 9     Value   : 27

Find value 5: 15

Remove Value 6

Key     : 0     Value   : 0

Key     : 1     Value   : 3

Key     : 2     Value   : 6

Key     : 3     Value   : 9

Key     : 4     Value   : 12

Key     : 0     Value   : 0

Key     : 6     Value   : 18

Key     : 7     Value   : 21

Key     : 8     Value   : 24

Key     : 9     Value   : 27

All the class code is in a header because templates classes can't be split between header and cpp without having the main method inside the cpp file. Is there something I should check or is it something to do with the code being inside the header?

EDIT: This is the code I'm using to get the output. It's in a file called "main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "DictionaryList.h"

using namespace std;


void main()
{
DictionaryList<int,int> list;

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    list.Add(i, i*3);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Key    : " << list.Exists(i*3) << "    Value   : " << list.Get(i) << endl;
}

cout << "Find value 5: " << list.Get(5) << endl;

cout << "Remove Value 6" << endl;
list.Remove(6);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Key    : " << list.Exists(i*3) << "    Value   : " << list.Get(i) << endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Presumably `keyPtr` and `valuePtr` are both `std::vector` instances?

Comment: Testing `keyPtr[i]` then removing `keyPtr.begin() + (i-1)` looks suspicious. And not just because of the redundant parentheses.

Comment: 'keyPtr' and 'valuePtr' are both 'std::vectors'.

The testing 'keyPtr[i]' then 'keyPtr.begin() + (i-1)' is the program going through the values in the vector keyPtr, with 'i' being the position in the vector. If it finds a match between 'keyPtr[i]' and the key variable in the parameter, then it erases the value at that position with 'keyPtr.begin() + (i-1)'.

I tested this on a normal 'vector<int>' variable outside a class and it worked normally.

Comment: You should be erasing `begin() + i`, not `begin() + (i-1)`. But I've no idea why you're getting `Key:0 Value:0` where the erased element was; could you post code you're using to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the observed output because:

- You are removing element 5 rather than 6. Having found the index `i` corresponding to the requested key, you then erase element `i-1`. Change the `erase` arguments to `begin() + i` to remove the expected key/value pair.
- Your output loop prints a line for each possible key, whether or not it's there, hence the line saying `Key : 0 Value : 0` where the removed element was. I guess `List.Exists()` looks up a value, returning a key if it's found and zero if it's not, and `List.Get()` returns zero if the key is not found. That behaviour will lead to errors: there's no way to distinguish missing elements from zero-valued elements.

Even if you don't want to use the standard map containers for some reason, I suggest giving your container a similar interface; as well as being familiar to people who use the standard containers, a lot of thought went into making their interfaces difficult to misuse.

Comment: For that reason, I realise it already worked to begin with. 

`list.Get()` and `list.Exists()` both return NULL if they can't find the key or value respectively, which in the case of integers means 0. Feel a bit stupid now. ^^' 

`Tvalue Get(Tkey key)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
  {
   if (keyPtr[i] == key)
   {
    return valuePtr[i];
   }
  }

  return NULL;
 }

 Tkey Exists(Tvalue value)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
  {
   if (valuePtr[i] == value)
   {
    return keyPtr[i];
   }
  }

  return NULL;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This looks very suspicious:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Key    : " << list.Exists(i*3) << "    Value   : " << list.Get(i) << endl;
}
```

When you test for your removed item (with key 5, value 15), I'll be that `list.Exists(i*3)` will return `false`, which `cout` will cast to `0` for you. Similarly, I bet you have a default return value of `0` from `list.Get`, too!

I'm of the opinion that at the very least, `list.Get()` shoudl throw an exception if asked for an absent key.